# Issue Binding Oracle Array Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I've been trying to call a procedure that takes in 3 different arrays as parameters but although I've tried a lot of different ways to do this I keep getting the exception saying that the amount or type of parameters is incorrect somewhere.
Can you guys help me figuring what exactly am I doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
 using (var command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.BindByName = true;
                command.Connection.Open();

                //Bind Client Ids Array to Database Parameter
                var nArrClientId = new OracleParameter("nArrClientId", OracleDbType.Int32)
                {
                    Size = clientIds.Length,
                    ArrayBindSize = new int[clientIds.Length],                        
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                };

                for (var index = 0; index < clientIds.Length; index++)
                {
                    nArrClientId.ArrayBindSize[index] = 12;                       
                }
                nArrClientId.Value = clientIds;

                //Bind DocNames Array to Database Parameter
                var vArrDocNum = new OracleParameter("vArrDocNum", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
                {
                    Size = docNums.Length,
                    ArrayBindSize = new int[docNums.Length],                        
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                };
                for (var index = 0; index < docNums.Length; index++)
                {
                    vArrDocNum.ArrayBindSize[index] = 20;                        
                }
                vArrDocNum.Value = docNums;

                //Bind Status Array to Database Parameter
                var vArrStatus = new OracleParameter("vArrStatus", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
                {
                    Size = statusArr.Length,
                    ArrayBindSize = new int[statusArr.Length],                       
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                };
                for (var index = 0; index < statusArr.Length; index++)
                {
                    vArrStatus.ArrayBindSize[index] = 15;                        
                }
                vArrStatus.Value = statusArr;

                command.Parameters.Add(nArrClientId);
                command.Parameters.Add(vArrDocNum);
                command.Parameters.Add(vArrStatus);                  

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();                  
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
```

This is the Procedure Definition on Oracle

```
   TYPE tnClientId IS TABLE OF clients.id%TYPE INDEX by pls_integer; -- Number (12,0)
TYPE tvDocNumber IS TABLE OF documents.document_number%TYPE INDEX by pls_integer; --VARCHAR2 (20 BYTES)

TYPE tvStatus IS TABLE OF varchar2(15);


PROCEDURE update_status (nArrClientId   IN tnClientId,
                     vArrDocNum     IN tvDocNumber,
                     vArrStatus     IN tvStatus);
```

Any help is more than welcomed

Comment: PL/SQL Table is not possible, you must use Associative Arrays, i.e. with `INDEX BY ...`

Comment: Not sure what that means :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Nested table`, you must use Associative Arrays.

I.e. `TYPE tvStatus IS TABLE OF varchar2(15);` is not possible you must use

`TYPE tvStatus IS TABLE OF varchar2(15) INDEX by pls_integer;`

What is the type of `clientIds`, `docNums` and `statusArr`? They must be arrays, perhaps you have to write like `vArrDocNum.Value = docNums.ToArray();`